# Bitshifting and making sure the last two digits are 10 in C

Tags: c, bit-shift

How do I bitshift so I only need to compare the first two digits in a number? Say I want to compare `10101011010` the last two bits and make sure it's `10`.

How would I do that?

Comment: With `if((x & 3) == 2)` and no shifting is needed, only masking to keep the 2 ls bits.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense! 
From wiki: "if both bits in the compared position are 1, the bit in the resulting binary representation is 1 (1 × 1 = 1); otherwise, the result is 0 (1 × 0 = 0 and 0 × 0 = 0)". So it makes sense that you & with 3 since this will only compare the first two bits and make the rest 0!

Comment: That's right: C doesn't accept binary notation, and decimal `3` is binary `11`. When you AND that with another number, the least 2 bits are preserved, and the rest are zeroed. For a larger value I might use hexadecimal for clarity, but `3` is the same in both notations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if certain bits are set in an integer, you'd use the binary `and` operator (`&`) and a mask. In the mask you set the bits you want to check and then use this mask to separate the bits you want to check.

So in your example:

`val = b10101011010`

And you want to make sure the last 2 bits are `10`:

`y = b10 = 0x02 = 2`

than you make the mask so it selects the last 2 bits:

`mask = b00000000011 = 0x03 = 3` (I'd use the hex notation to make it more clear)

or you could use bitshifting:

`mask = (0x01 << 0) | (0x01 << 1)`  (setting bit 0 and bit 1 and `or`ing them together)

Now we use the binary `and` operator:

```
val  = b10101011010
mask = b00000000011
& -----------------
res  = b00000000010
```

--> now we have our bits we are interested in

and we compare `res` with the value you want them to be:

```
if (res == y)
// -> good
else
// -> bad
```